# CC Avenue USD Payment in PHP query

Tags: php

I am implementing CC Avenue payment integration through PHP. I have already set INR payment. But my query is how can i set USD payment on the same form. The form actually a donation form. Below is my form

```
<form method="POST" id="donateForm" name="customerData" action="ccavRequestHandler.php" novalidate="novalidate">
<input name="tid" id="tid" readonly="" value="xxx" type="hidden">
<input name="merchant_id" value="xxx" type="hidden">
<input name="order_id" value="xxx" type="hidden"> 
<input name="currency" value="INR" type="hidden">
....
</form>
```

Can someone please help me how can i do this?

Comment: sorry dont know the details of every payment gateway on the planet.

Comment: usually, you send the param of currency to the payment gateways. Look in the documentation for this

Answer (score 0):

Please see this.

**Can I offer the products on my site with INR as well as USD pricing while maintaining a single CCAvenue account. If yes, should I use two different shopping cart links for this purpose?**

*>> You may represent your product pricing in any number of currencies. At the end of the transaction when your client has to check-out to the CCAvenue payment option page, we require that the payment amount is in INR equivalent only. This is because we do not process the final payment in any other currency but INR; because of RBI rules and Regulations. And no, you do not have to create a separate shopping cart link for the various currencies.*

Ref:https://mars.ccavenue.com/faq_ccav.jsp#19

Comment: Thank you. So i need to convert USD amount to INR and then proceed for payment. Is it right?

Comment: Yes. You need to convert USD to INR.